# Unable to compile bspwm

Tags: debian, window-manager, bspwm

I've recently tried to switch from i3 preconfigured with archLabs to bspwm un debian. After I installed the base packages for Debian I install the necessary dependencies of bspwm as I saw in a guide online. I started by compyling xdo, then sxhkd and when trying to compile bspwm I get an error saying "fatal error: xcb/shape.h: No such file or directory(not exact words as I'm translating from Spainsh) #include < xcb/shape.h > seems to cause the error and it's one of the first lines of a c file on src/window.c".
Please submit any possible fixes to this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install (at least) `libxcb-shape0-dev`.